# build strophoid in java

Tags: java, function, jframe, draw

Can you tell me how to draw a [strophoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strophoid)?
I wrote this loop to build it

```
for (int i = 0; i < 360; i += 5) {
                double u=Math.tan(i);
                x[i] = (int) (a * (Math.pow(u,2)-1)/(Math.pow(u,2)+1));
                y[i] = (int) (a * u* (Math.pow(u,2)-1)/(Math.pow(u,2)+1));
                gfx.drawLine(x[i], y[i], x[i], y[i]);
            }
```

but I get something like this [graphic](http://clip2net.com/s/4MHweU)

Comment: Anonymous downvoter/closevoter:  You don't post your reasons (which is your right), but I disagree with your close vote.  It's clearly a real question, and programming, and the asker did work and got stuck.  It was clear enough that drorb below could answer it.  So I'm upvoting "For Great Justice".

Comment: I guess a "strophoid" might be a unknown object for many.

Comment: @madth3 Yes.  I'm one of them.  But `gfx.drawLine(x[i], y[i], x[i], y[i]);` kinda stands out.

Comment: gfx.drawLine(x[i], y[i], x[i], y[i]) - just draw something like 1 point... in the loop it's like one line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well.. i found the solution using JFreeChart

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;


import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataItem;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;



public class Strofoida extends JFrame {


public Strofoida() {
    super();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    XYSeries series = createSeries();
    XYDataset xyDataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
    JFreeChart localJFreeChart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("", "X", "Y", xyDataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
            true, true, false);
    XYPlot localXYPlot = (XYPlot) localJFreeChart.getPlot();
    localXYPlot.setDomainZeroBaselineVisible(true);
    localXYPlot.setRangeZeroBaselineVisible(true);
    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(localJFreeChart);
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(800, 600));
    setContentPane(chartPanel);
}

private XYSeries createSeries() {
    XYSeries ser = new XYSeries(new XYDataItem(0, 0), false);
    int a = 1;
    for (double f = -0.9; f <= 0.9; f += 0.01) {
        double u = Math.tan(f);
        ser.add(a * (u * u - 1) / (u * u + 1), a * u * (u * u - 1) / (u * u + 1));
    }
    return ser;
}

static class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Strofoida strofoida = new Strofoida();
        strofoida.pack();
        strofoida.setVisible(true);
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with this line: `gfx.drawLine(x[i], y[i], x[i], y[i]);`
You are using the same index `i` for both ends of the line, so you actually draw a point.

Comment: ok, if i write gfx.drawLine(x[i], y[i], x[i+1], y[i+1]); it not completly change the graphic(

Comment: how can you use x[i+1] if it is not yet initialized?

Comment: @user2167382 Are you sure you are using correct formula for calculatiing x and y values?

Comment: i try to many formulas but no one draw wrigth fuction [link](http://clip2net.com/s/4MIi3v)

Comment: @user2167382 Your link doesnt show correct formula. Try using this [--> link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Strophoid.html)

Comment: @Smit well i try this parametric equation [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RightStrophoid.html) but it is still like line on Oy axis

Comment: @user2167382 I found some links which could be useful to you. [--> Right Strophoid](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Curves/Right.html)  and [-->  
(right) strophoid](http://www.2dcurves.com/cubic/cubicst.html)

Comment: @user2167382 One more thing calculate your points in another loop and then draw lines in another loop like you previously stated `gfx.drawLine(x[i], y[i], x[i+1], y[i+1]);`

Comment: since i is incremented by 5 it should be gfx.drawLine(x[i], y[i], x[i+5], y[i+5]);